# Why is Symfony2 rendering a <input type="text"> instead of <input type="number"> for a form field of type number

Tags: forms, html, symfony

In Symfony2 forms you have the following two from field types (among others):
`number`: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/number.html
`integer`: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/integer.html

My questions is why the `integer` type renders `<input type="number">` and the `number` type renders `<input type="text">` thus missing the HTML5 new input types attributes (min, max, step)?

Is there a decent and clean way to configure a `number` form type to render an `<input type="number">` tag (form theming seems a bit dirty to me)?

**Edit**
Seems like changing the field template is the only option, even though it states a comment `{# type="number" doesn't work with floats #}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it could work for `number` too, if they set the attribute `step="any"`. However, you can overwrite the block for the `number`-widget and change it to:

```
{% block number_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('input') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock number_widget %}
```

Check this link, to see the default form layout template:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

**Edit**

This is only a wild guess, but maybe they are not setting `number` to not confuse the user. 
When you're on an English system Chrome will accept a value like **1.9**. When you type this into Chrome on a German system, the value will be corrected immediately to **19**. On a German system you have to type **1,9**. Chrome will change this to **1.9** on submit. Imagine the confusion for an unexperienced user who travels a lot. :)

Comment: as you've probably noticed in form_div_layout.html.twig (provided at your link) they left a comment `{# type="number" doesn't work with floats #}`

Comment: Haha, I've looked at this so often and never read this comment. :)